# Rounding off the Decimal In number C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to round off the decimals to int in C#

eg 
1.2 -- 1

1.44 -- 1

1.45 --- 2

1.445 --- 2

1.7 ---2

Comment: What are the exact rules you want for the rounding? Your example does not match any of the usual ones.

Comment: 1.2 -- rounds to 1.. everything happens but 1.45 rounds to 1.. i want it to be 2. if there are 3 decimals eg 1.445--- then it should round to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
float f = 1.44, g=1.445;
int i;
i = floor(f+0.555555);
// Output 1
i = floor(g+0.555555);
// Output 2
```

**Floor function :**

> This function returns the nearest integer which is less than or equal
>   to the argument passed to this function.

And you have to include math.h header file to use this function.

Hope it will help.

Comment: 5.49 -- should be made 6.. but round makes it 5.